# Arch Linux: Dovecot Sieve Script Won’t Compile

Tags: spam, dovecot, spamassassin, arch-linux, sieve

- Arch Linux
- Linux kernel 4.9.36 (64-bit)
- Dovecot 2.2.31 (65cde28)
- SpamAssassin version 3.4.1 running on Perl version 5.26.0
- Pigeonhole 0.4.19-1

Trying to set up a mail server for the firs by following the Arch Linux Wiki’s [Sieve tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dovecot#Sieve) (which I wound up on from following the [Virtual user mail system tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Virtual_user_mail_system)).

---

This is supposed to enable `spamtest` and `spamtestplus`. Verbatim what the Wiki calls for with the exception of `sieve_trace_debug` and stripping out the docu-comments for legibility.

`/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf`:

```
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve

  # Start Arch Linux Wiki Config <https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dovecot#Sieve>
  sieve_extensions = +spamtest +spamtestplus

  sieve_spamtest_status_type = score
  sieve_spamtest_status_header = \
    X-Spam_score: (-?[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]).*
  sieve_spamtest_max_value = 5.0

  sieve_before = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/global_sieves/move_to_spam_folder.sieve
  # End Arch Linux Wiki Config

  sieve_trace_debug = yes
}
```

---

This is supposed to route SPAM e-mails into a Junk folder.

`/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/global_sieves/move_to_spam_folder.sieve`:

```
require "spamtestplus";
require "fileinto";
require "relational";
require "comparator-i;ascii-numeric";

if spamtest :value "ge" :comparator "i;ascii-numeric" "5" {
  fileinto "Junk";
}
```

---

Tried to compile the above.

`$ sudo sievec /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/global_sieves/move_to_spam_folder.sieve`:

```
move_to_spam_folder: line 1: error: require command: unknown Sieve capability `spamtestplus'.
move_to_spam_folder: line 6: error: unknown test 'spamtest' (only reported once at first occurrence).
move_to_spam_folder: error: validation failed.
sievec(foo): Error: failed to compile sieve script '/var/lib/dovecot/sieve/global_sieves/move_to_spam_folder.sieve’
```

---

Didn’t work because it couldn’t find `spamtest` and `spamtestplus`. So I tested the configuration.

`sudo sieve-test -t - -Tlevel=matching /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf /home/foo/test.eml`:

```
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: expected end of command ';' or the beginning of a compound block '{', but found unknown characters.
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '~'.
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: expected end of command ';' or the beginning of a compound block '{', but found unknown characters.
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '.'.
90-sieve.conf: line 2: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '.'.
90-sieve.conf: line 5: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 5: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '+'.
90-sieve.conf: line 5: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '+'.
90-sieve.conf: line 7: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 8: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 8: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '\'.
90-sieve.conf: line 9: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '-'.
90-sieve.conf: line 9: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '-'.
90-sieve.conf: line 9: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '+'.
90-sieve.conf: line 9: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '.'.
90-sieve.conf: line 10: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 10: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '.'.
90-sieve.conf: line 12: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: line 12: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '.'.
90-sieve.conf: line 15: error: unexpected character(s) starting with '='.
90-sieve.conf: error: parse failed.
```

Apparently it can’t even read `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf`? And it’s choking on the equals sign??

It seems if I fix this error, I can enable `spamtest` and `spamtestplus`, which will in turn [potentially] fix the `sievec` compilation error.

---

`doveconf -n`:

```
# 2.2.31 (65cde28): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.19 (e5c7051)
# OS: Linux 4.9.36-x86_64-linode85 x86_64 Arch Linux
mail_home = /home/vmail/%d/%n
mail_location = maildir:~
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-client {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/private/vmail.crt
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
```

Comment: `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf` is not sieve, but Dovecot configuration -- `sieve-test` will not be able to understand it. What's the output of `doveconf -n`?

Comment: @JensErat Edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sieve-specific configuration is not sourced by Dovecot at all. If you use "per-feature" configuraiton files, your `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` file should include a statement like

```
# Most of the actual configuration gets included below. The filenames are
# first sorted by their ASCII value and parsed in that order. The 00-prefixes
# in filenames are intended to make it easier to understand the ordering.
!include conf.d/*.conf
```

which sources the individual configuration files in `conf.d`.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. The Arch Linux Wiki article completely left that part out. In fact, it even warns against it, saying: “Note: If you instead want to modify `dovecot.conf.sample`, beware that the default configuration file imports the content of `conf.d/*.conf`. Those files call other files that aren't present in our configuration.”